# How to change the js order in mvc temple and a single view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My temple has the js  to change the grid width and every view in my project using this temple.But now I have a page which also want to change the grid width.I want the js execution order is temple firstly ,and second order is the single view.But in fact the single viewjs is always execute first.How to change this order?

**Mvc temple js(use in every view)**:

```
$(function(){
 $("#mygriddiv").width($("#containerdiv").width()-200);
});
```

**Single View js**:

```
$(function(){
 $("#mygriddiv").width($("#containerdiv").width());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your temlate view define an optional section for javascript resize script, that can be defined in the views, and render the generic resize javascript when that view is not defined.

in your template layout:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("ResizeJS")){
    @RenderSection("ResizeJS", false)
}
else {
   <script>
      $(function(){
          $("#mygriddiv").width($("#containerdiv").width()-200);
       });
   </script>
}
```

And in the view that you want different resize logic, just define your section with the resize script that is applicable for that view.

```
@section ResizeJS 
{
   <script>
     $(function(){
        $("#mygriddiv").width($("#containerdiv").width());
      });
   </script>
}
```